# How to find in a node template file that node is loaded directly or from 'node_load' function?

Tags: 6, nodes, theming

I want to check, in a node template file (node-node-type.tpl.php), that code is executing because of a direct request from a user visiting a node page or from calling node_load function in somewhere else?

**EDIT**:

the problem was `'Number of posts on main page'` option in `'Post settings'`. its value was 30 (I don't remember why I set it to its maximum value but I'm sure there was a reason that wasn't related to it's true functionality I think it triggers something else).

now that we know problem is from `'Number of posts on main page'` option how I
can I fix it?
why this option invokes node template file despite the fact that I use a custom `page.tpl.php` which doesn't call `node_view` at all?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? Thanks

Comment: `node_load` is a core function no node can be loaded without this call.

Comment: @ninjascorner a node template file executes: 1- when a user see that specific node type(=content type) page e.g. node/nid 2-when there is a call to node_load(nid).Now in node-node-type.tpl.php how can I check that?

Comment: Please, explain WHY. Maybe we can find better solution :)

Comment: @sepehr `node_load()` doesn't ever invoke the node template file. It's a function for loading a node, it has zero connection to the theme layer. I think you're getting it confused with `node_view()`, which _does_ invoke the node template file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** I realise after writing the answer that I sound rather negative. Sorry about that, but I can't phrase this in a positive fashion.

**Answer:** First, and foremost, you are mixing logic, with output. The template should *not* have logic in it, and should absolutely *not* care about *why* it was called.

When a user visits `node/1`, core will call `node_load(1)`. This is in no way different from calling `node_load(1)` anywhere else.

A node template does also *not* execute as a direct result of loading a node. Templates are used when the theme layer *renders* a node, which is the completely other end of the response.

You *can, in theory,* call [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to get the call stack, and from there figure out more information about from where node_load was called, but there is almost certainly exactly **0** valid use-cases for this. I guarantee that you do not want to go down that path, and even considering it means that something is seriously wrong.

I have built Drupal-sites professionaly for years now, and have done some *really, really* ugly hacks during that time. Neither of them would come anywhere near analysing the stacktrace, **in the theme layer**.

Comment: For debug and exploration purposes [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)'s `ddebug_backtrace()` can be used too.

Answer (score 1):

node will displayed after creating renderable array via `node_view(node_load($nid))`. so if there is somewhere where you render node yourself, you can pass extra variable to node_view and catch it in `node--node-type.tpl.php`

another solution is using [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module, where you can set static variable and get it in `node--node-type.tpl.php` then unset it again

```
context_set('mynamespace', 'customrender', true);

print drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid))); //and in node--node-type.tpl.php context_get('mynamespace', 'customrender');

context_set('mynamespace', 'customrender', false);
```